# How should I store an alphabetically ordered list of nodes' name in Neo4j?

Tags: node.js, data-structures, neo4j

I'm building a small Web App using Neo4j as the main database. All my nodes (~700,000) have a common property, say `name`. I have build an unmanaged extension for the Neo4j server with Java (Jax-rs).

What I would like to do is to be able to quickly get the nodes for which `name` matches some pattern. I figured it would be easier to store the list of all nodes (already sorted) but my issue is how should I do that. For the webApp I'm using Node.js and React (with a Redux architecture) if this is relevant.

First of all, should I use my Neo4j's unmanaged extension, and either

1. create a node with properties equal to the list of all other nodes and make my calculation based on that node's properties
2. use the unmanaged extension to access a file on the server and read/write on that file to get what I want. n that case I wouldn't use the Neo4j api but I wouldn't have to have an other database running

An other possibility would be to use an other database like MongoDb and connect to this one from Node.js. Or even read/write a file directly from Node.js.

These are the options I can think of right now, I hope I've been clear enough. What would be the best practice?

Thanks for your help,

Comment: What kind of pattern? You can put an index on the `name` property and this will allow you to quickly find nodes matching many kinds of patterns, including inequality, starts with, and membership checking.

Comment: I'm confused why the storage itself needs to be sorted (you'd likely need to build a relationship tree between content to achieve that). Cypher allows you to query data and then order the results. Also, I don't know why you're thinking of using a second database (mongodb in this case) as a first step to then access your neo4j data - is this again related to sorting? Not sure what you're asking. It would probably help if you edited your question and showed the type of queries you're trying to execute, so that it makes more sense.

Comment: @ToreEschliman I thought about indexing but didn't know that I could then easily perform such kinds of pattern matching, so thank your that. What I want to build is a kind of a real time process and the whole matching would have to be fast... will I have performance issue with this method if my app grows?

Comment: If you are *only* going to use the inherent relationships provided by ordering or parameter filtering, then you have a million better options than a graph, SQL or NoSQL. Graph databases work best when you want to explore explicit declared relationships between objects.

Comment: @ToreEschliman I know, this is not (at all) the main purpose of the graph. I'm actually doing some graph-specific calculation, but to connect that with the UI (like being able to search among nodes from the client) I need a way of retrieving the nodes' name. And this was actually my question, would you recommend using index within neo4j to perform that or build a separate database just for that purpose? I could make both solutions work but just wonder what would be considered best practice...

Comment: If you can do it with one of the patterns listed [here](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/3.0/cypher/#query-schema-index), then absolutely best practice would be to stick with one database. If your query pattern complexity exceeds that, and your data size is going to be substantial, you'll need to figure out a way to represent your pattern as an actual graph path (pre-seed it with leaf nodes). The extra complexity of integrating with an external index is almost never going to be worth it unless it's absolutely mandatory.

Comment: @ToreEschliman Alright, that's what I was looking for, thanks a lot.

Comment: @ToreEschliman Actually, could you please elaborate a little bit on what you mean by "a way to represent your pattern as an actual graph path (pre-seed it with leaf nodes)", I'm not very familiar with those concepts... I get the point but I'm just curious. If you add that as an answer I could mark it as the correct solution. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As per request, an (admittedly contrived) example of pre-seeding your graph with leaf nodes for complex queries: Let's say you want users to be able to query to find all nodes that have a `name` property that is all lowercase (say it signifies a pseudonym). If you run `EXPLAIN` on a basic query for this, you'll find it does a `NodeByLabelScan` or, worse, an `AllNodesScan`, because you can't perform this operation on the index. So, when you add nodes, you would `MERGE` them with a relationship to a leaf node signifying whether or not their `name` property meets this condition:

```
MERGE (a:DataNode)
SET a = {input}
WITH COLLECT(a) AS datanodes
WITH datanodes, [b IN datanodes WHERE b.name = lower(b.name)] AS lowers
FOREACH(lower IN lowers|
    MERGE (q:QueryLeaf {condition:'all_lowercase', match: True})
    MERGE (q) - [:INCLUDES] -> (lower) )
```

And then, when you get a 'lowercase' query coming in:

```
MATCH (q:QueryLeaf {condition:'all_lowercase', match: True})
WITH q
MATCH (a:DataNode) <- [:INCLUDES] - (q)
WITH a
```

and then go about the rest of your query.

This will do the processing once when you load data, rather than every time you query it. If your data is fairly static, the extra complexity and time spent writing will make it well worthwhile.